# How do I set postgresql sequence ownership in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to add a sequence column, separate from id, to my Entries table with this migration:

```
class AddSequenceToEntrySerial < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq;'
    change_column :entries, :serial, :integer, default: -> { "nextval('entry_serial_seq')" }
    execute 'ALTER SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq OWNED BY NONE;'
    execute 'ALTER SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq OWNED BY entries.serial;'
  end

  def down
    change_column :entries, :serial, :integer, default: nil
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq OWNED BY entries.serial;
      ALTER SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq OWNED BY NONE;
      DROP SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq;
    SQL
  end
end
```

However, I get the following error:

```
PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to
: ALTER SEQUENCE entry_serial_seq OWNED BY entries.serial;
```

I'm a bit lost for what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes due to trying to override the existing sequence for a table..in order to escape the error for an existed sequence while importing

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
        CREATE SEQUENCE your_seq_name
            START WITH 1
            INCREMENT BY 1
            NO MINVALUE
            NO MAXVALUE
            CACHE 1;
        ALTER SEQUENCE your_seq_name OWNED BY your_table.id;
        ALTER TABLE ONLY your_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('your_seq'::regclass);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Created Sequence for your table';
        EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'sequence "your table seq" already exists, Skipping';
            -- do nothing, its alread exists there
END
$do$;
```

As you are trying to create sequence for an already created table you need to catch the exception as mentioned in the above solution ..!

http://gopikrishnajonnada.blogspot.com/2016/08/sequence-must-havesame-owner-as-table.html